# Is it possible to integrate Forest admin into parse server?

Tags: express, parse-platform, parse-server, forestadmin

Would really like to be able to integrate [forest](http://www.forestadmin.com/) into parse server. Currently they have a npm plugin that works with express+mongoose, was wondering if it was possible to configure parse server as an express app with mongoose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATE] Forest Admin relies on a dedicated admin backend automatically generated. So it does not depend on any specific framework anymore.

[Parser server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) is built on top of Express.js. [Forest Admin](http://www.forestadmin.com) already supports Express with Mongoose, Sequelize and Loopback.

You cannot use `forest-express-mongoose` directly because the Forest npm plugin (the Liana) will try to analyze the database schema through mongoose, which does not exist in Parse-server.

[Forest Admin](http://www.forestadmin.com) supports [Loopback](https://loopback.io) today with the npm plugin (the Liana) [forest-loopback](https://github.com/ForestAdmin/forest-loopback). The Parse server support is similar to the Loopback.

You can create a forest-parse plugin with the same architecture. Both modules just need to use the common `forest-express` module to generate the Admin API. The only responsability of the forest-express-mongoose, forest-express-sequelize, forest-loopback and forest-parse is to analyze the database schema through the ORM used and map it to a "Forest valid schema" (also called apimap in the documentation: http://doc.forestadmin.com/api-reference/#initializing-your-admin).